# using signalR to update multiple views with 1 broadcast

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using MVC 5 with signalR 2.  I have a page that has a main layout template that uses signalR to update some part of that template.  I also have a partial view on that page that needs to refresh from that same signalR broadcast that the layout template is using.  Basically in the template i have:

```
 var entrypush;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        entrypush = $.connection.entryHub;
        entrypush.client.entryUpdated = refreshLayout;
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
```

but the partial view will need to respond to this same 'entryUpdated' broadcast call from signalR.  What is the best way to handle this?  Should i just create an entirely new hub on the partial view, so that i have?

```
var entrypushPV;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        entrypushPV = $.connection.entryHub;
        entrypushPV.client.entryUpdated = refreshPartialView;
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
```

This seems like a bad idea but i can't think of a way around this.  Would it be better to duplicate methods on the hub instead?  So that instead of just pushing 'entryUpdated', I then push 'entryUpdateForLayout' and 'entryUpdateForPartialView'?  That way i could avoid creating duplicate hubs, but I'm duplicating push calls in this way instead.

Comment: Both template and partial will merge into a single page when loaded, right? So then, you will have a single point for handling the event. Just be sure to call it only in the page that needs it

Comment: yes, but the partial view may or may not exist.  Or i may have several different possible partial views.  The layout doesn't know what partial view will be there, so it doesn't know what method (in it's hub) to call for that partial view

Comment: then you can maybe declare a function in your partial and on the layout have the function to handle the event. Inside, check if the partial-view function exists, and if so call it

Comment: you're assuming that there is only 1 or a few possible partial views.  The template is the layout for my entire website.  The partial views are really just the loaded pages inside the website, which can have partial views in itself.  The permutations of possibilities for what you're suggesting are prohibitive in itself.    I would rather not have 100 different checks on my template check if  'is this view loaded?  No?  Then is this view loaded'?  I feel like either of the 2 options that i've mentioned above would be more efficient.

Comment: could you not just override `refreshLayout` in your partial? or do you need to run the logic in `refreshLayout` aswell as extra logic in the partial?

Comment: i need to still run both.  They are both going to refresh data on their section of the page from the same signalR broadcast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to preface this by saying that I am by no means a JavaScript wizard, so take this with a grain of salt, and modify it as necessary. In this code, I open a connection to my SignalR hub in a javascript file, and then create an event which is raised when a client side function is invoked. Then you can listen to this event where needed:

**hubconnection.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var entrypush;
    entrypush = $.connection.entryHub;

    //setup event
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('refresh', true, true);

    //define the function that is called when entrypush.client.entryUpdated is called. obj is data passed from the hub
    refresh = function (obj) {
        event.data = obj;
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    };

    entrypush.client.entryUpdated = refresh;

    //connect to hub
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    //jquery + SignalR stuff...

    <script src="~/Scripts/hubconnection.js"></script>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener('refresh', function (e) {
        //do stuff with e.data here, if necessary.
    }, false);
    </script>
</head>
```

**_Partial**

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('refresh', function (e) {
            //do stuff with e.data here, if necessary.
        }, false);
</script>
```

If this is unclear, or it seems like something is missing, let me know.

Comment: No, that's awesome and should fit what i need very well.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 nice solution, solved a problem I have had for a while (I resorted to multiple hubs) but this will be much cleaner, thanks